# Filtering a dictionary + Tuple

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dictionary, tuples

So i've load a pickle file an got these dictionaries here:

```
 {1536: {'origin': u'HW', 'department': u'Kunde', 'events': [(1411562482304633L, u'new'), (1421683468875977L, u'closed')]}, 

 {1537: {'origin': u'HW', 'department': u'Kunde', 'events': [(1411562809498852L, u'new'), (1414071035946802L, u'closed')]}, 

 {1538: {'origin': u'HW', 'department': u'Kunde', 'events': [(1411562928759247L, u'new')]}
```

as you can see there is a tuple called 'events' which can contain one or more events.
I want to display all of these dictionaries which contain an event named 'closed'.

i've tried it this way but it doesnt work

```
ticketdata = pickle.load(open("tickets.p", "rb"))

for i in ticketdata:
    for j in ticketdata[i]['events']:
        if 'closed' in ticketdata[i]['events']:
            print i, ticketdata[i]['events']
```

Comment: Well you would need to elaborate more on *doesn't work* , what are you getting instead? Also is `ticketdata` a dictionary?

Comment: i dont get anything, just blank space. yes its a dictionary

Comment: Your current example seems like you have 3 different dictionaries? Or is it a single dictionary with three keys?

Comment: You may a have key error in your pickle is it true.

Comment: these are 3 different dictionaries and i only want to display the ones which contain an event named 'closed'

Comment: `print(ticketdata)` can you show exactly what that prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking if 'closed' is in the list of tuples, but not in the tuple itself, so it will never match. You're already iterating over the list of tuples with `j`, so just check if `closed` is in `j` instead.

```
ticketdata = pickle.load(open("tickets.p", "rb"))

for i in ticketdata:
    for j in ticketdata[i]['events']:
        if 'closed' in j:
            print i, ticketdata[i]['events']
```

Answer (score 0):

In a pythonic way, you can do this:
Put all your dic in a list named lst_dic and:

```
dic_closed = [dic for dic in lst_dic for evt in dic.get('events',[]) if 'closeed' in evt]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for two `for` loops:

```
ticketdata = pickle.load(open("tickets.p", "rb"))

for (i,j) in ticketdata.iteritems():
    if 'closed' in j['events']:
       print i,j['events']
```